# Lexical scope of my

Tags: perl

Pretty much every perl program written uses this idiom:

```
{
open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) || die "you lose";
print $fh $blah;
}
```

However, I don't want to die, I want to just skip the print.
So I write:

```
{
print "you lose\n" unless (open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) and print $fh $blah);
}
```

and get "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at ./o.pl line 5" for my trouble.

Removing the my (bad form) eliminates this error, as does:

```
{
my $fh;
print "you lose\n" unless (open($fh, '>>', $filename) and print $fh $blah);
}
```

but why?

Why, in the broken code, doesn't `$fh` exist from `open(my $fh...` to the close of the block (the `}`)?

Comment: *"Pretty much every perl program written uses this idiom"* Oh if only that were true!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `my` doesn't take effect until the end of the statement.

For that same reason, `my $x = $x` won't see the new `$x` on the right hand side of the statement.  It'll see the old `$x`.

For example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = 42;

{
    my $x = $x + 1;
    print "inside, x = $x\n";
}

print "outside, x = $x\n";
```

This prints:

```
inside, x = 43
outside, x = 42
```

Your `open` statement is roughly equivalent to the inner `my` statement above.  If you had `$fh` declared in the outer scope, surprising fun would happen:  You'd probably end up printing to the wrong file.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation.  PS, seems to me that perl fails big time here on the principle of "least surprise".

Comment: enable strict and warnings if you want least surprise (or at least notification of surprise)

Answer (score 5):

You may prefer

```
{
  open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) || warn "you lose";
  print $fh $blah if $fh->opened;
}
```

Of course you can also remove the `warn` if you wish.

If your Perl 5 is older than version 14 then you will need to add

```
use IO::File
```

to the header of your code.

Answer (score 4):

If you add `strict` and `warnings` to your program, you would get much more useful error messages:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
   my $filename = "test.txt";
   print "you lose\n" unless (open(my $fh, '>>', $filename) 
         and print {$fh} $blah);
}

__END__
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 6.
Global symbol "$blah" requires explicit package name at test.pl line 6.
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

The problem being that you can't declare and use a lexical variable in the same statement. `$fh` will only be available *after* the line with the `open` on it.

Comment: yes and no; the new lexical is "returned" by the my and so can be used.  you can't refer to the lexical *by name* in the same statement.

Comment: That makes sense. The name will only be added to that scope's symbol table after the execution of the statement right ?

Comment: no, it's added at compile time, but restricted to a specific range of statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare lexical variable and use it in the same statement.

However you can,

```
open($_, '>>', $filename) and print $_ $blah for my $fh;
```

or

```
open($_, '>>', $filename) ? print $_ $blah : print "you lose\n"
  for my $fh;
```